# Possible bug in Android's databinding member's generation names

Tags: android, android-databinding

I ran into what I think is a bug on Android's databinding class generation mechanism and I would like a second thought so I can know for sure and report it officially. I noticed that the strategy to build binders' names is to either fill the name with random characters, or to truncate them at a specified lenght.

**Layout structure: fragment_add_property.xml**

```
layout > ScrollView > LinearLayout > CardView > LinearLayout > LinearLayout
> TextInputLayout > EditText (or) AppCompatEditText


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText android:id="@+id/et_add_property_colonia"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:inputType="textCapWords"
      android:text="@={prop.colonia}"
      android:hint="Colonia"/>
```

**Binding class: FragmentAddPropertyBinding.java**

```
public class FragmentAddPropertyBinding extends android.databinding.ViewDataBinding implements android.databinding.generated.callback.OnClickListener.Listener {
     ...
     public final android.widget.EditText etAddPropertyColonia;
     public final android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText etAddPropertyCalle;
     public final android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText etAddPropertyDescription;
     ...
     private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener etAddPropertyColonia = new android.databinding.InverseBindingListener() {
         ...
     }
     ...
     private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener etAddPropertyCallean = new android.databinding.InverseBindingListener() {
         ...
     }
     ...
     private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener etAddPropertyDescrip = new android.databinding.InverseBindingListener() {
         ...
     }
}
```

Notice the name duplication of `etAddPropertyColonia` as a view and as a binder listener.

So I started adding a bunch more with the same name structure, but changes in:

- only vowels (1)
- vowels and consonants (2)
- interchanging vowels for consonants with same tokens (3)
- letters for symbols keeping string lenght(4)

These are my findings (removed visual noise):

```
(1)  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText   
         android:id="@+id/ut_idd_preparty_calanui"> 

(2)  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
         android:id="@+id/um_ipp_nwinuwms_jiriqei"/>

(3)  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
         android:id="@+id/ad_pye_tacdrion_poelrot"/>

(4)  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/abcd_i_prol_rvbqa_gab_ue"/>


Error:(124, 56) error: variable adPyeTacdrionPoelrot is already defined in class FragmentAddPropertyBinding
Error:(176, 56) error: variable etAddPropertyColonia is already defined in class FragmentAddPropertyBinding
Error:(462, 56) error: variable umIppNwinuwmsJiriqei is already defined in class FragmentAddPropertyBinding
```

Strangely, with this particular set, `ut_idd_preparty_calanui` did not show up, as it did when I first added it before the other rest. Two of the names with this setup are completely changed in the binding listener:

```
private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener mboundView4androidCh
private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener mboundView5androidCh
```

**EDIT**

I noticed I was missing a character in my last view, results updated.

Thank you for your input

Comment: I have faced this problem multiple time but I ended up by changing ID. I have also noticed that sometime binding create exact name as we defined as ID for internal USE. Can you try by changing "etAddPropertyColonia" to "etAddProColonia". Just give a TRY !!

Comment: Please read the question again. I'm not asking for any type of advice to solve my code here

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using? I just want to be sure that it isn't already fixed in 2.3.

Comment: Wanna give me a job @GeorgeMount? :D

Comment: :-) Would you try with 2.3 to see if it is fixed? We fixed many bugs between 2.2 and 2.3 and I think this is one of them.

Comment: I'll sure do and post a comment here. Cheers!

Comment: I think 2.3 is still on Canary though